# Fragments Navigation in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hai i'm new to this fragments development in android. My Question is navigation between the fragments. I have a button in fragment 1 and a text view in fragment2 and i have activity activity1 where i declared both these fragments in xml. My question is when i press the button in fragment1, it has to carry some text and display in the textview of fragment2 before that it has to check whether the fragment2 is in the same layout or not?

Code will be very helpful to me. Thanks in advance..........

Comment: Why won't you just use Google? There are tons of tutorials on this topic.

Comment: can you please provide me some of the links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first declare your inflater into onCreateView (in 2ndFragmentClass) like below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);

    return view;
}
```

Please consider fragment_content must at lease have a TextView inside itself (So that we set its value inside the fragment). Then we have to change the value of this text from the 1st fragment. So we add this constructor inside our 2nd Fragment (the fragment containing TextView) like below:

```
public void setText(String name) {
    TextView txt= (TextView ) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt.setNewText(name);
  }
```

Simply, it would be like below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);

    return view;
}
public void setText(String name) {
    TextView txt= (TextView ) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt.setNewText(name);
  }
```

Then we must define which text must be set into 2nd Fragment **from 1stFragmentClass.** Then we set the text of the 2nd fragment by pressing button in 1st fragment like below:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String url = "Hello, This is the text from 1st Fragment:)";
         //Here we try to declare 2nd fragment.
    2ndFragmentClass fragment = (2ndFragmentClass) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
        fragment.setNewText(url);
}
```